# Next.js page doesn't show up in window

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, routes

I created a next.js project with App Router and under app folder my file structure looks like that:

```
    *some other files*
    .
    .
    user 
    | [id] 
    |  | page.tsx
    | @users 
    |   | page.tsx 
    | layout.tsx 
    | page.tsx
```

I want to make a parallel routing and show users list and spesific user on the same page when the url matches /user/[id] (eg. /user/12)

My layout.tsx file inside user

```js
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
    children: React.ReactNode,
    users: React.ReactNode
}

const UserLayout: NextPage<Props> = ({ children, users }) => {
    return <div className='flex flex-row items-center w-screen h-screen'>
        <div className='font-normal text-4xl text-slate-500 basis-60 flex-shrink text-center'>
            Users
        </div>
        <div className='flex-grow'>
            {users}
        </div>
        <div className='flex-grow'>
            {children}
        </div>
    </div>
}



export default UserLayout
```

(i changed the contents & styles in the file, whatever...)

On user/12, the page renders layout and [id]'s page but not @users page. I tried to move [id] folder to inside of @user-profile file and added it to the user's layout but it didn't work either. How can i do that?

Thx,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

If you try to log `users` to the console from the Layout component, you probably get `undefined`, so no matter how hard you try, the component will not show up on your Layout component. The reason for this is because the compiler doesn't see the `@users` folder. You just need to restart the server and it should work out just fine.

You posted this yesterday, so I assume when you come back to it, if the local server was shut down, it should work fine by now, but you might try to create more parallel routes later on and it might just save you some time in the future.

** I don't know if it's just the current nextjs release that has a bug, or if it's more deeply rooted, so this answer might be obsolete later.

Comment: thanks, i just closed and haven't opened yet. I will check it out if i find time :)